# Four-acceleration properties

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, acceleration, vectors

Is the four-acceleration time-like, null, or space-like? How would we derive the answer? Do we start from $a \cdot a$?

Answer (score 0):

One could compute $\tilde a \cdot \tilde a$ if you knew the 4-acceleration $\tilde a$ and the definition of "spacelike".

Do you have an expression for $\tilde a$ and the definition of "spacelike"?

One could also use the properties of the 4-velocity $\hat v$, which is timelike and has constant square-magnitude, and how $\hat v$ is related to $\tilde a$.

(Hint: consider a similar problem: a particle in uniform circular motion.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any time-like four-velocity

$$
\eta_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu=c^2=const
$$

Where $\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$

And that four-acceleration is:

$$
a^\mu=\frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}
$$

(for trivial metric and spacetime)

Now use $\frac{d\left(c^2\right)}{d\tau}=0$ to prove that four-velocity is perpendicular to four-acceleration